# Is it possible to have usb controllers too bridge connections?

Tags: networking, usb, usbserial

I was just wondering if i could connect 2 usb devices together that are both connected to the same pc. Instead of the pc being connected, i want to have the devices connected together as if they were directly connected through cable. I ask this because I actually don't have a cable converter right now to connect my Android to the PS3 controller, then suddenly i came with the idea of doing it like this. Just like a network bridge.